# rxjs observable.of(object) returns {"_isScalar": "", "value": {}, "scheduler": "" } instead of value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am fairly new to rxjs.

I tried to create a function that runs a angular 2 http request like that:

```js
syncFromApi$() {

  // create Headers
  ...

  let ob$ = this.http.post(
    CONFIG_APP.apiEndpoint + '/sync/app',
    '',
    { headers: headers }
  )
  .map((response:Response) => {
    return Observable.of({type: "success", payload: response.json()});
  })
  .catch(function (err:Response) {
    return Observable.of({type: "error", payload: err.json()});
  });

  return ob$;
}
```

In short, when having success, I am returning an Object which indicates, if the request was successful. After that I want to switch map depending on the returned object:

```js
let o$ = syncFromApi$()
  .switchMap((value) => {
    console.log("value", JSON.stringify(value, null, 0));
    if (data.type === 'success') {
      return Observable.of(1);
    } else if (data.type === 'error') {
      return Observable.of(2);
    }
  });
```

And here comes the problem I face. The console.log(...) outputs a object like this:

```js
value, {"_isScalar": true, "value": THIS_IS_WHAT_I_NEED_AS_VALUE, "scheduler": null}
```

But I need only the object I returned with the syncFromApi$ function.

Can anyone explain to me, if I am using `observable.of()` in the wrong manner?

I tried `observable.of(1)` and it returns 1 as value. If I use a object (`observable.of({ type: "myType", message: "myMessage" })`), it returns an object wrapping the object I need with the keys "_isScalar", "value" and "scheduler".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you return an Observable from your mapping function, and not just the object? You don't want an Observable of Observables.

Comment: i later want to subscribe to the chain of observables

Comment: map transform an observable of x into an observable of y thanks to a function transforming x into y. No need to wrap y into an Observable.

Comment: if i remove Observable.of() around the object in the catch block, my typescript compiler complains with the following message: ```app/app/services/state.ts|116 col 14 error| Argument of type '(err: Response) => { type: string; payload: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<{ type: string; payload: any; }>) => Observable<{}>'. Type '{ type: string; payload: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '{ type: string; payload: any; }'.
```

Comment: What's in catch looks OK to me. What's in map doesn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is in your `map` operator:

```js
let ob$ = this.http.post(
  CONFIG_APP.apiEndpoint + '/sync/app',
  '',
  { headers: headers }
)
.map((response:Response) => {
  return {type: "success", payload: response.json()}; // <----
})
```

You need to return an object not an observable. The `map` operator uses the object like it is and doesn't project the returned observable into the observable chain.

If you want to return `Observable.of` for some reasons, you need to use the `flatMap` operator instead:

```js
let ob$ = this.http.post(
  CONFIG_APP.apiEndpoint + '/sync/app',
  '',
  { headers: headers }
)
.flatMap((response:Response) => {
  return Observable.of({type: "success", payload: response.json()});
})
```

That's fine for the `catch` operator since it expects an observable to be returned into its associated callback.